# Is it possible to recreate the "new" operator in JS?

Tags: javascript, reflection

I recently read the [MDN documentation on the `new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new), and I was struck by the concise description of what it does:

> When the code new *Foo*(...) is executed, the following things happen:
>
> 1. A new object is created, inheriting from Foo.prototype.
> 2. The constructor function *Foo* is called with the specified arguments and this bound to the newly created object. `new Foo` is equivalent to
>      `new Foo()`, i.e. if no argument list is specified, *Foo* is called
>      without arguments.
> 3. The object returned by the constructor function becomes the result of the whole new expression. If the constructor function doesn't
>      explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is used
>      instead. (Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can
>      choose to do so if they want to override the normal object creation
>      process.)

It seems like none of those things are privileged operations, so is it possible to completely recreate the action of `new` with other language constructs?

Note that I don't count [`Reflect.construct`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct) since the very definition of it is that it "acts like the new operator as a function".

Comment: Notice that since ES6 you *must* use `Reflect.construct`, the above description is from ES5. A few builtins as well as constructors defined using `class` syntax *do* distinguish between being invoked as a constructor and being invoked like a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function pretty much recreates `Reflect.construct`, and thus `new` (with the exception of `construct`'s last argument, which has no equivalent when using the `new` operator:

```
function fauxNew (constructor, args) {

    // allocate a new object and set the prototype
    var newObject = Object.create(constructor.prototype)

    // call the constructor with "this" bound to the new object
    var retVal = constructor.apply(newObject, args || [])

    // if the constructor returned an object, return it; 
    // otherwise return the new object
    var constructorReturnedAnObject = 
        !!retVal && ["object", "function"].indexOf(typeof retVal) !== -1
    return constructorReturnedAnObject? retVal : newObject
}
```

Here is [the same code presented alongside some test cases](https://tonicdev.com/n3dst4/faux-new).

Comment: Don't trust `typeof` when detecting an object. It may return strange things for non-callable non-standard exotic objects, e.g. `"unknown"`. `Object(retVal) === retVal` is more reliable.